# Display html text in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net

I have a some of html strings that my application generates. Each html 'snippet' is stored as a collection of strings. I need to display some of these according to the user query. What is the usual way to display html stylized texts in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can embed IE in Windows Forms with the [WebBrowserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28VS.85%29.aspx).  You might be able to stream the text in, otherwise you might have to write to a file and point the control to that file.

Comment: Thanks! Did it by setting DocumentStream property of WebBrowser component.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "web browser" component