# Winforms control for displaying html text

Tags: c#, html, winforms, tags, controls

I am coding a Windows Forms Application in C#, and one of the requirements is to display some html code in a control, with the correct colors that correspond to the relevant tags.

E.g. When right clicking on a webpage in Google Chrome, then selecting View Page Source, a form is shown with all the html, correctly formatted, with tag colors and each line of code's line number.

Is there a free, reliable control that can do this? Is there an inbuilt Microsoft control that does this?

As I am new to this area of coding, can someone please provide me with some useful names, and some resource links if possible? I am not sure of the correct name for a control that does this, and as such, my Google searches have not come up with what I am looking for.

Also, the control needs to be trustworthy.

Thanks

Comment: Use WebBrowser control. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428617/display-html-text-in-windows-forms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465258/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-html-content-on-a-windows-form

Comment: @Kumar he wants to display formatted, non-rendered HTML text

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383574/c-sharp-perfect-syntax-highlighting & related *syntax highlighting* questions

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) control. It's open source and has HTML syntax highlighting as well as many other features.